# How to have a gitlab CI job to be triggred only manual on branches and always automatically on master?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a pages job that I want to run manual on branches, but automatically triggered on master:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  cache:
    paths:
      - public
  script:
    - scripts/pages.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 2 days
```

So I want a combination of:

```
  only:
    - master
  when: always
```

```
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
  when: manual
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 13):

This should be possible to do if you use [GitLab CI rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules). This is an example where the shell is powershell and it shows the current time and branch/tag name:

```
pages:
  script:
    - mkdir public
    - date > public\index.html
    - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME >> public\index.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == null'
      when: never
    - when: manual
```

GitLab matches each individual rule from top to bottom. If the branch is named 'master', the job gets marked with `when: always`. If the branch name is null, this is a tag, and the job is marked with never. If this is not a branch named `master`, nor a tag, this is a normal branch, and the job is marked with manual.

**As Aleksey Tsalolikhin described, you can remove this rule:**

```
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == null'
      when: never
```

You will then get the option to run the pipeline for your tags as well, like this:

[image: Rules for manual job for both tags and branches, except master branch]

If this is what you want or not, that is up to you.

Comment: Do you mind though if I give the bounty to Aleksey? He expounded quite a lot on the basis you have here and improved on some details and ran some tests. However, it was based primarily on this answer, so if you want the bounty you can have it. Aleksey though did a good job and is a new contributor, so...

Comment: I looked through the docs before and didn't see rules. Must have been blind. Sweet. Yeah, this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: GitLab CI has become quite big, so it is easy to miss things! As for the magical Internet points, it is not so important :-)

Answer (score 8):

I've tweaked the answer by MrBerta -- the third command was missing the `echo` command.

I also changed the slashes from backslashes to regular forward slashes so I can use the Linux shell rather than Powershell.

It now works.

Here is the gitlab-ci.yml file -- with credit to MrBerta.

```
pages:
  script:
    - mkdir public
    - date > public/index.html
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME >> public/index.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == null'
      when: never
    - when: manual
```

I tried pushing to master, and my GitLab Pages content was updated as expected; and I tried pushing to a feature branch, and the manual "Play" button came up in the CI/CD pipeline UI.

When I pushed a tag (with detached head, i.e., not on any branch), I could not test it -- GitLab CI did not run a pipeline automatically, and when I tried to Run Pipeline, and picked my tag, GitLab threw an error: "The form contains the following error: No stages / jobs for this pipeline."

So, I would simplify this to:

```
pages:
  script:
    - mkdir public
    - date > public/index.html
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME >> public/index.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      when: always
    - when: manual
```

This pages job runs manually on branches (and tags but I couldn't test it), but automatically triggered on master, as the original poster requested.

Comment: Thanks for showing an example with bash! If you remove the `if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == null': when: never`, then you will get an option to run the pages job if you push a tag. If the tag is detached, and refers to a commit that you haven't pushed, I would consider that tag to be an error.

Comment: Adding for completeness: Gitlab has since renamed `master` to `main`. Also, if you have `main` is your default branch, you can use it like so: `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH`

Answer (score -1):

You will need to define two stages. you can either copy/paste or use anchors:

```
.deploy_stage: &deploy_stage
  stage: deploy
  cache:
    paths:
      - public
  script:
    - scripts/pages.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 2 days

deploy_manual:
  <<: *deploy_stage
  only:
    - branches
  when: manual

deploy_master:
  <<: *deploy_stage
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work, as the job has to be called "pages" for gitlab to pick this up as a pages deploy.